# How to delete a record and assign an existing record in its place

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm wondering if anyone could help me out here.

Is it possible when deleting a record to assign all instances of the deleted record to a new record?

For example:

For each project in a time planning database, i can assign a worker as team leader for each project. If there was a duplicate entry for a team leader i would need to delete one of the instances of these details. If you did this you would then be left with empty values for the records assigned to this 'team leader'. This would be a problem.

I appreciate that you would want to nip this in the bud, so to speak, and not allow duplicate entries. However, if you would need to delete a record is it possible to assign a separate record in its place?

Hope that makes sense, if you could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cascade update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304466) is a possibility, but probably overkill for something that will only happen occasionally and should not happen at all. I suggest that you run a query to update the relevant records before you delete the team leader:

```
Update Projects Set TeamLeaderID=123 
Where TeamLeaderID=456
```

Comment: I can't see how CASCADE UPDATE would do any good if the FK is an Autonumber. All that CASCADE UPDATE is update FKs when a FK value is updated, and since Autonumbers can't be updated, it would have no effect. Of course, if the PK of the record being deleted is not an Autonumber, CASCADE UPDATE would work, but you couldn't just change it to the value of the existing record you want to point the records to, as this would cause a collision on the PK's unique index. So, I just don't see what role CASCADE UPDATE could play in solving this problem.

Comment: The OP says 'and not allow duplicate entries' which suggests some design problems, which might make cascade update a possibility, however, you may notice that I said 'possibility', I did not say 'recommended'. I have found cascade update useful from time to time when cleaning data.

Comment: I'm not disputing that sometimes it might be useful, but in this case I can't conceive of any way it would help address the question.

Comment: Cheers for the advice here folks appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. It is a matter of knowing, where your *worker* is referenced, finding all such locations and replacing the reference through a new reference to another worker. Once all references to the *old* worker have been removed, you can delete the worker.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub test()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sql As String


Set db = CurrentDb
sql = "select worker_id from worker_ref_table"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!worker_id = "new value"
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Close

sql = "select worker_id from worker_table"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.delete
Wend

rs.Close

End Sub
```

See also [VB Database Programming](http://www.vbexplorer.com/VBExplorer/vb_feature/june2000/Database_Beginner_ADO_DAO.asp) for further help on connecting and operating on a database. Please note, that VB and VBA are not the same. You should be able to use the above code inside Access VBA to accomplish this task.

Comment: Why are you stepping through the tables when you can simply run an update query?

Comment: I guess, once I learned something that works, but isn't quite the prime time way of doing things, I tend to stick to old ways. Using this method, I was able to update several fields on a remote sql server table. Might well be, that other methods are easier...